# How to grab variables from a txt file needed for processing in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a txt file named `setup.txt` that contains the following data:

```
DSN=ZXP.SOURCE
PATH=/z/zxp/20211015
SCHEMA=ZXP
URL=https://zxp-support.mybluemix.net/contest/4q21/contact-sheet
OUTPUT=OUTPUT(RESULT)
REPORT=q421report
```

I need to pass this file as a parameter to my script but as a novice in shell scripting
I get errors when using `source setup.txt` which seems like it executes anything in the file.

```
input="$1"
source $1

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
  then
    printf "Usage Example: ./q421droop5.sh setup.txt \n\n"

    exit 1
fi
if test -f "$input"; then
    echo "$input exists."
    content=$(cat $input
fi
echo $DSN
echo $SCHEMA #echoing the variables give me errors
```

How can I access the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapfile` and `declare`:

```bsh
$ mapfile -t a < setup.txt
$ declare "${a[@]}" 
$ echo "$DSN"
ZXP.SOURCE
$ echo "$SCHEMA"
ZXP
```

Comment: This works like a charm!

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks, duly noted, edited the answer. When I tested I didn't add the quotes, I added them here so I didn't see the newlines.

Comment: The problem now is when I try to pass shell commants like ```DB2="java com.ibm.db2.clp.db2"
$DB2 -tvf decrypt.sql > parse_decryption1.txt
key=$(python3 decryption.py) ``` I get the errors :```./executor.sh: line 30: java: command not found ```

Comment: ... I mean even commands like ```sed```give : ```./q421drop5.sh: line 32: sed: command not found```

Comment: @Fnechz Welcome, [edit] the question adding new requirements, the code you show is not in the question.

Comment: I have edited now

Comment: @Fnechz: your `setup.txt` file redefines your `PATH` variable and nullifies any path previously specified to access your binaries on your system. That is the reason you cannot access `sed`, `java`, `python`, etc... Log out and back into you terminal and edit `setup.txt` to take out the `PATH=...` line. Everything will come back to normal.  If you need the PATH info you specify, add it like so in your file: `PATH=$PATH:/z/zxp/20211015`

Comment: Oh I realize, let me do that

Answer (score 0):

Nice trick with the `declare` command. But why not use "command substitution" like

```
declare  $(<setup.txt)
```

?

Comment: for the very simple reason that it doesn't work. The quoted expansion produces a single argument `DSN=ZXP.SOURCE\nPATH=...`, and the command then assigns the whole lot to `DSN`. (with nothing in the other named vars)

Comment: Thanks @ilkkachu. Taking away the double quotes seems to make it work. Edited in post.

Comment: until there's something like `THIS=foo bar`, or `THAT= *` in the file, yes. Not that broken lines, ones without the `=` sign wouldn't break the `declare` anyway, but whitespace is more likely to come up

Comment: I need to pass different text files with different variables that should be used as indicated in the edit above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `setup.txt` is meant to contain one `variable=value` per line, here, I'd do it using an associative array:

```
typeset -A field=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
  case $line in
    ([^=#]*=*) field[${line%%=*}]=${line#*=}
  esac
done < setup.txt
```

And use:

```
printf '%s\n' "${field[DSN]}" "${field[PATH]}"
```

That avoids the arbitrary command injection vulnerability (like with `a[$(would-rm -rf ~)]=gotcha` that also affects the `declare`-based approaches) and in your example avoids clobbering the `$PATH` variable which is  a critical one for the shell.

Comment: I get empty output by runnig the code above

Comment: @Fnechz, I get `ZXP.SOURCE` and `/z/zxp/20211015` lines as the output of that `printf` command with the `setup.txt` given as sample in the question. Even if first part failed to set the `$field` associate array properly, that `printf` command would at least give you two empty lines.